# Pointers to pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Hi have a function which takes the argument of a pointer, to a pointer to a struct. I'm having trouble accessing the members of my struct. Do struct pointers behave differently to pointers of other types, or am i just missing somethign essential?

```
struct mystr {
int num;
};

void fun(mystr **out) {
  printf("%d",**out.num); <-- where the problem arises
}
```

Comment: "I'm having trouble" is not a good description. What problem do you have? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Have you tried `(*out)->num`?

Comment: Pay attention to compiler messages

Comment: Look up the c operator precedence, because `.` is evaluated before `*` in your case, so you may also use `(**out).num` but `(*out)->num` is cleaner because `->` already dereferences the pointer of your struct..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, 'struct pointers' (whatever you mean) work precisely the same way as pointers to other types.

You just need to recall [operators precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

1. `.` structure member access
   `->`structure member access through pointer
   (...)
2. `*` indirection (dereference)
   (...)

So your expression `**out.num` is interpreted as `*(*(out.num))` and your `(out.num)` is **not** a pointer, hence applying an asterisk to it is an error.

You need to parenthesise appropriate part of the expression to force a non-default operators binding: `(**out).num` – dereference `out` twice first to get to a `struct mystr` variable, then access that variable's `num` member.

The `->` operator serves as a shortcut for accessing a member of pointed stucture:
`(ptr_expr)->member_name` is equivalent to `(*(ptr_expr)).member_name`
so you can replace `(**out).num` with `(*out)->num`.

Answer (score 1):

Possible to the solution to use this :

```
printf("%d",(*out)->num);
```

instead of

```
printf("%d",**out.num);
```

Comment: Please avoid giving code only answer, and explain why this works.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you should implement, here `printf("%d",(*(*out)).num);` will print `1`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct mystr{
int num;
};

void fun(struct mystr **out) {
printf("%d",(*(*out)).num); 
}

int main()
{
struct mystr m;
struct mystr *p;
struct mystr **pp;
p=&m;
pp=&p;
m.num=1;
fun(pp);
return 0;
}
```

Here `m` is our structure, `p` is pointer to structure and `pp` is pointer to the pointer `p`.